# The difference between "Object *obj" and "Object &obj"

Tags: c++

graph.h

```
struct Edge {
    int from;
    int to;
    unsigned int id;
    Edge(): from(0), to(0), id(0) {};
};

struct Vertex {
    int label;
    vector<Edge> edge;
};

class Graph: public vector<Vertex> {
    int gid;
    unsigned int edge_size;
};

class Trans {
public: 
    int tid;
    vector<Graph> graph;
};
```

`vector<Trans> database;` `database` is a global variable, then i call `run_algo(database);` in main function.

```
void run_algo(vector<Trans> &db) {
    EdgeList edges;
    for(unsigned int tid = 0; tid < db.size(); tid++) {
            Trans &t = db[tid];
            ...
       Graph g = t.graph[gid];
```

I want to ask `db` is a alias to `database`, `db[tid]` is a Transaction vector, but what if the difference between using `Trans &t = db[tid];` and `Trans t = db[tid];`, since the author who write the sample using `Trans &t = db[tid];`, but i think it should use `Trans t = db[tid];`

Thanks:)

Comment: The title and the question don't appear to match. At all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After

```
Trans &t = db[tid];
```

t is and behaves exactly as the item in db[tid], you change t, you change db[tid]

With

```
Trans t = db[tid];
```

t is merely a copy of the item in db[tid], changing t won't change db[tid] here.

Answer (score 2):

```
Trans &t = someVar;
```

Is making `t` a reference to the variable. Whereas

```
Trans t = someVar;
```

Would invoke the copy-constructor of `Trans` and create a completely new object.

See http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html for more information as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Trans t = db[tid];
```

creates a new object using the copy constructor. All changes are applied to this new object.

```
 Trans& t = db[tid];
```

is an alias for `db[tid]`. Any changes to `t` will also apply to `db[tid]`.

Answer (score 1):

As vector::operator[] returns an object by reference, then using

```
Trans &t = db[tid];
```

will be more effecient, as it does not force a copy of the object stored in the vector - unlike:

```
Trans t = db[tid];
```

However, in the first case, any changes to 't' will change the object stored in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `Trans &t` and `Trans t` is that the first is a reference, which is basically an **alias** for another variable, in this case, whatever is being taken out of the vector.  The other is `Trans t` which is a new variable, where the stuff in the vector is being copied by using `operator=` to copy the data.

Using the reference avoids the copy made when you use `Trans t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Trans &t = db[tid];
```

means that `t` is an alias of the object `db[tid]`. an alias is a different name for the object but the left and right values are equals to left and right values of `db[tid]`. so if you make some modification to `t` you will have same modification on `db[tid]`.

while :

```
Trans t = db[tid];
```

means that `t` is made with a copy of the object `db[tid]`. so if you edit `t`, `db[tid]` will not be affected.